# Request for reporting apiv4 for google analytics

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-analytics-api

today i try to do a request with reporting API v4 to get data from google analytics. I write in google app script to display data in google spreadsheet.

Here's my function:

```
function get_ga(){
  var now = new Date();
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();       
  var site = doc.getSheetByName("Dashboard").getRange(2,1).getValue();
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName("Google analytics");
  var service = getService(); 
  if (sheet==null){
    sheet = doc.insertSheet("Google analytics"); 
  }
  start_date=getstart(now);
  end_date=getend(now);

  if (service.hasAccess()) {

    var apiURL = 'https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet';

    var headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + getService().getAccessToken()};

    var request = {
      "reportRequests":
      [
        {
          "viewId": VIEW_ID,
          "dateRanges": [{"startDate": start_date, "endDate": end_date}],
          "metrics": [{"expression": "ga:users"}]
        }
      ]
    }




    var options = {
      "headers" : headers,
      "contentType":'application/json',
      "method" : "post",
      "payload" : JSON.stringify(request),               
      "muteHttpExceptions": true
    };

    try {
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiURL, options);
    } 
    catch (e) {
      Logger.log(e);
    }
    Logger.log(response)

    var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());        
    console.log(result);

    if (result.error){
      return null;
    }


  }

  else {
    var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
    Logger.log('Open the following URL and re-run the script: %s', authorizationUrl);
    return 0;

  }

}
```

Of course i have a OAuth2.0.gs file with:

```
function getService() {
  // Create a new service with the given name. The name will be used when
  // persisting the authorized token, so ensure it is unique within the
  // scope of the property store.
  return OAuth2.createService('searchconsole')

      // Set the endpoint URLs, which are the same for all Google services.
      .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth')
      .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')


      // Set the client ID and secret, from the Google Developers Console.
      .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
      .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)

      // Set the name of the callback function in the script referenced
      // above that should be invoked to complete the OAuth flow.
      .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')

      // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())

      // Set the scopes to request (space-separated for Google services).
      // this is Search Console read only scope for write access is:
      // https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters
      .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters')

      // Below are Google-specific OAuth2 parameters.

      // Sets the login hint, which will prevent the account chooser screen
      // from being shown to users logged in with multiple accounts.
      .setParam('login_hint', Session.getActiveUser().getEmail())

      // Requests offline access.
      .setParam('access_type', 'offline')

      // Forces the approval prompt every time. This is useful for testing,
      // but not desirable in a production application.
      .setParam('approval_prompt', 'force');
}


function authCallback(request) {
  var searchConsoleService = getService();
  var isAuthorized = searchConsoleService.handleCallback(request);
  if (isAuthorized) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success! You can close this tab.');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied. You can close this tab');
  }
}
```

Finally i have a variables.gs file with my differents ID and my VIEW id from google analytics, corresponding to the website i want data from. Something important is that i see data in google analytics but i'm not the owner of the website ;

```
    //GSC
var CLIENT_ID = '*******************************************';
var CLIENT_SECRET = '*****************';

//GA
var CLIENT_ID2 = '************************************';
var CLIENT_SECRET2 = '**************';
var VIEW_ID = '********';
```

with google search console and google analytics API enabled.
All my functions are perfectly working with google search console.

The error is:{"error":{"status":"PERMISSION_DENIED","code":403,"message":"Request had insufficient authentication scopes."}}
The first thing strange i noticed is that i use client ID and client secret from Google Search console for authentification for google analytics (see my OAuth2.0.gs file) but it seems to work; otherwise i 'll get a 401 error.

Answer (score 2):

When using Google API's from google apps script, you will want to use [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) for the [Analytics Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/analytics). Be sure to [Enable the service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) in your script.

Once enabled, auto-completion in the script editor for the new methods become available. Type `AnalyticsReporting.` to see it.

For [Analytics Reporting batchGet](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet) the method would be `AnalyticsReporting.Reports.batchGet(resource)`

Example use:

```
function get_ga(){
  var now = new Date();
  var start_date=getstart(now);
  var end_date=getend(now);

  var request = {
    "reportRequests":
    [
      {
        "viewId": VIEW_ID,
        "dateRanges": [{"startDate": start_date, "endDate": end_date}],
        "metrics": [{"expression": "ga:users"}]
      }
    ]
  }

  var response = AnalyticsReporting.Reports.batchGet(JSON.stringify(request));

  Logger.log(response)
}
```

[**Note:** Im using your request object and assuming it is correct, as I do not personally use analytics and have not tested the code. However, [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) all work the same within google apps script. Basically, just piece together the JSON representation objects from the [Google Analytics Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/) and use it as the argument in the desired API advanced service method.]

Comment: Like a beginner , i enabled the API in the google API console and not in the dialog. Your function works perfectly, thank you, you actually saved my life.

Comment: @JeanSec you should mark this as answered by ticking the checkmark